# How to type an array of generic functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have something that I'm having trouble typing. I was able to reduce the problem to the following minimal example. I have a function where the first argument is generic and constrained to something that is serializable as JSON.

```js
type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [property: string]: Json };
type Foo<A extends Json> = (n: A) => boolean;

const a: Foo<number> = (n: number) => n + 1 > 0;
const b: Foo<string> = (n: string) => n.endsWith("a");
```

I need a type definition for an array of these functions where the generic part can be anything that the generic part of Foo allows.

I understand why this doesn't work.

```js
const foos: Foo<Json>[] = [a, b]; // Error
```

And, `any` is too loose. It allows values that aren't valid `Foo`s such as this example where the argument to the function is an `HTMLElement` which is not assignable to `Json`.

```js
const foos: Foo<any>[] = [a, b, (n: HTMLElement) => true]; // Invalid, but no error
```

What I need is a union of all the concrete types of `Foo`s that are allowed in this array. However, that union would have to be infinitely long to cover anything that could be equivalent to `Json`.

```js
type SomeFoo = Foo<string> | Foo<number> | ... | Foo<Record<string, Record<string, [number, string[]]>>> | ...;
const foos: SomeFoo[] = [a, b];
```

Is there a way to use generics or some other mechanism to avoid this infinite union?

**Edit:**

In case it helps, here's a slightly more complicated example that's closer to the real-life code I'm trying to type: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxTsATgSyQcygB8okBXAWwCMItioqEEAbCAQxRPOefvmQDaAXXoBvKALBYEkLKABcGbHnxDF-FAF8A3AChdoSFACyIACrgIAHgCCUCAA9gEJABM4sREgB8aKKN0oIKgAMyZFAAoASjRfGz1ghjYsSKRFGxjUX0YWdiQ9HX0AY2RMKDZFUwtIK0xcAl90AMSwhEjM3wAiNk6AGkDgqmTUjtIAOhd3AHUcYAALCO7OqN1C3RKkMqpFACUIEqxXWuUCXpNzSysNb0b-cqgdIA). I have an object with two functions. The return type of the first function needs to match the first argument of the second function.

**Edit 2:**

This question was refactored significantly based on feedback from the comments, but it's still asking the same fundamental question.

Comment: Is there any common trait between your generic function arguments? Seems to me you should just use `any` or `{}` since you won't be able to determine what type a member function accepts apart from a `const` array. Maybe you could explain how you intend to use this?

Comment: Yes, there's a more complex type than I've shown, but for this example, the type of the argument can only be string or number. The actual type is recursive, so the duplication approach won't work.

Comment: `Generic` should be `string & number`, but I think it's pretty much the same as `any`. Since as @ConnorLow has noticed, `string` and `number` don't share any common trait here.

Comment: The type `((n: string) => boolean) | ((n: number) => boolean)` is almost entirely useless, since you can't determine at runtime which kind of function it is, and therefore you can't call it with an argument it definitely accepts. You almost certainly want something else instead of this type, but to know what you actually want, you'll need to explain [what problem you are trying to solve](https://xyproblem.info/) by using this type.

Comment: I realize this example is quite contrived and not useful in any way. But, I'm hearing loud and clear that this is not something TypeScript is capable of expressing. I might ask another question later about how to solve my specific problem. This question was about the capabilities of the type system and it shouldn't drift from that focus.

Comment: It's not that typescript is uncapable of expressing this, it's that this type doesn't quite make sense. Imagine the code in your sandbox worked, then how would it be used? For example I could do `b['a'].bar(123)` and this should work, because type signature `Record<string, MyType<Json>>`  says me that `b['a']` is of type `MyType<Json>`, consequently `b['a'].bar` is of type `(n: Json) => boolean`, so I should be fine passing a number to it, but in fact it only expects a string. This is the problem that you need to bypass, not that typescript is arguing

Comment: Like I said, I understand why that approach doesn't work. I used it in the sandbox example because it was the closest I could get to expressing what I really want. Clearly that wasn't helpful. For example, `const b: Record<string, MyType<string> | MyType<number>> = { a };` works, but it would be impossible for that union to include every type that could possibly be equivalent to `Json`.

Comment: Your playground example is more evocative than the code in your question; you might want to rewrite the question to be like this instead. In any case what you're looking for is called *existentially quantified generics* (whenever you think you need an infinite union, this is what you want) and they are not directly supported in TS (see [ms/TS#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)). You can emulate such types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3z1LN). If that meets your needs I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Yes! Thank you! Existentially quantified generics is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll make an update to the question. I'd love to see a writeup of your solution, but I'm not sure it will work for me since it requires adding a wrapper function. I'm adding `d.ts` to an existing JavaScript library and can't change the code to call the wrapper.

Comment: The updated example code still doesn't help; there's nothing useful you could ever do with a value of type `SomeFoo`, even if TS had existential types. You can't call a function of type `<∃T>(x: T)=>void` because it takes *some* argument you don't know; it has no purpose. Your playground example is much more reasonable, since `<∃T>{foo(): T, bar(x: T)=>void}` *is* usable, as it would let you call `v.bar(v.foo())`; the `bar()` argument type is still unknown to you, but you know it's the *same* as what comes out of `foo()`. Can you use `MyType` and not `Foo` in your question?

Comment: Also, when you say you are describing an existing JavaScript library, it's vaguely possible that you can alter the existential emulator to fit, since universally quantified generics (the "normal" generics in TS and most other languages) look existentially quantified when you switch the consumer and the provider of the data.  Presumably whatever functions that consume arrays-of-things could be made universally quantified generics, alleviating the need for the arrays themselves to be existentially quantified. But I'd need some motivating [mre] to show a concrete suggestion.

Comment: So, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9Jq7m) is how I'd probably deal with a library typing; forget about trying to write the infinite union for the array type, and just let the compiler infer something stronger.  Then make `processMyTypeArray()` generic the normal way.  Let me know which of these versions of things you want to see written up, preferably by editing the code in the question to motivate a solution.  A toy example,  but not one so "minimal" as to be useless.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your patience. You've been extremely helpful. I was trying not to change the question so much that it's not the same question any more. I'll probably have to just create another question and delete this one. I must admit, I don't understand why the example is "useless". I can see how it's not completely typesafe, but that's the nature of the library I'm writing this for. I can't know some of the types until runtime.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I guess if I don't care about calling those functions, then you could do something [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Nlp6rN) to represent your library function that accepts an array of such functions and complains if any of them require their argument to be something not extending `Json`.  Does that work for you?  If so I think you still might need the example to have a sketch of the library function signatures for the answer to be applicable.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I can adapt that to cover at least most of what I need.

Comment: So what do you want to see here?  Should I answer as-is or do you want to include a sketch of the library function signature you care about?

Comment: I was able to adapt your example to completely solve my problem. Thank you! Since I have a solution I'm happy will, I'm not going to take the time to rewrite the question again. But, I would appreciate an answer for the question as is. I still have some study to do to understand conditional types and mapped types used in your example, so it would be nice to have a good explanation of how you used those to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem that makes this particular example hard to discuss is that, on the face of it, a value `foo` of type `(n: A) => boolean` (where `A` is some unresolved [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter that extends `Json`) cannot safely be called.  I can't call `foo(123)` because while `123 extends Json`, I would need to know that `123 extends A`, which I don't know.  `A` is a mystery to the caller of that function.  It's as if the function is saying "I want something but I won't tell you what it is", and unless you use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) or [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), TypeScript's type system won't even let you guess.   In what follows I will ignore this problem and just use type assertions, but it would have been nicer if the question had something more motivating (e.g., a type like `{val: A, consumer(val: A): void;}` with an unknown `A` would be usable because you could always safely pass the object's `val` to its own `consumer` method).  Oh well.

---

Anyway, whenever you find yourself wishing you had an "infinite [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)", it's a sign that you want to use [*existentially-quantified generics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types). If these existed in TypeScript, you could write something like:

```
// not valid TS, don't try this
type SomeFooArray = Array< <∃A extends Json> Foo<A> >;
```

where `<∃A extends Json>(...)` means "there [*exists*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%83) an `A` assignable to `Json` for which the enclosed expression holds, but I don't know or care what `A` is".

Unfortunately, like most languages with generics, TypeScript only directly supports *universally-quantified generics*, which acts as an infinite [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), where `<A extends Json>(...)` means "the enclosed expression holds for *all possible* `A` types that are assignable to `Json`".

There is an open feature request for existential types at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), but who knows if it'll ever be implemented.

---

One thing about universal-vs-existential quantification, and unions-vs-intersections is that they are [duals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)) to each other, and that one thing can be transformed into its dual by changing the role of data producer and data consumer.  It therefore turns out that you can emulate existential types by representing them as a `Promise`-like data structure.  Instead of handing you a `<∃A extends Json> Foo<A>`, I hand you a

```
type SomeFoo = <R>(cb: <A extends Json>(foo: Foo<A>) => R) => R;
```

It's a function that holds its `Foo` in a black box, and you can pass callbacks into it.  The function calls the callback with its `Foo` as a parameter and hands you back the return result.  Anything you could do with a `<∃A extends Json> Foo<A>` could be done with a `SomeFoo`:

```
function acceptSomeFooArray(someFooArray: SomeFoo[]) {
    return someFooArray.map(someFoo => someFoo(foo => foo("hmm"))); // boolean, but
    // -------------------------------------------------> ~~~~~
    // '"hmm"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', 
    // but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Json'.
}
```

Oh, darn, there's that error because you cannot safely call it.  Fine:

```
function acceptSomeFooArray(someFooArray: SomeFoo[]) {
    return someFooArray.map(someFoo => someFoo(
        (<A extends Json>(foo: Foo<A>) => foo("hmm" as A))) // assert
    );
}
```

Anyway, it's easy enough to turn a concrete `Foo<A>` into a `SomeFoo`:

```
const toSomeFoo = <A extends Json>(foo: Foo<A>): SomeFoo => cb => cb(foo);
```

And so you could pass an array of `SomeFoo` where an array of `<∃A extends Json> Foo<A>` is wanted.  As long as you can change your data structures, this is a viable solution.

---

Oh, but you have an existing library whose data structures you can't alter.  In that case, it is still possible to use an alternative of switching the producer with the consumer.  Instead of trying to come up with a specific type that means "`Foo<A>` for some `A`" and apply it to pieces of data, you instead go to any library function which needs to deal with data of this sort and make it generic so it can handle a `Foo<A>` for *all* `A`.

For example, if you have a library function `processFooArray` that accepts a heterogeneous array of "some" `Foo`, you can declare it this way:

```
type DistribFoo<T> = T extends Json ? Foo<T> : never;

// declaration 
declare function processFooArray<A extends readonly Json[]>(
    arr: readonly [...{ [K in keyof A]: DistribFoo<A[K]> }]): [...{ [K in keyof A]: boolean }];
```

Here, `DistribFoo<T>` takes any union of `T extends Json` and [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) `Foo<T>` across it, so that `DistribFoo<string | number>` becomes `Foo<string> | Foo<number>`.  This helps in case `processFooArray()` takes an unordered array type.

And `processFooArray()` is generic in `A`, an *array* type of `Json` elements.  Then the `arr` value it accepts is a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  When you call `processFooArray(arr)` the compiler can [infer the `A` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) from `arr`, and use it to validate that each member of the array is actually a `Foo<T>` for some `T`.

Note that I've made the return type an array of `boolean` values of the same length as the input `arr`, under the assumption that the function will (somehow!) call each function and map each function to its output.

Let's test it:

```
const a: Foo<string> = (n) => n.endsWith("a")
const b: Foo<number> = (n) => n < 0.5
const c = (x: HTMLElement) => x.hasAttribute("src")
   
processFooArray([a, b]); // okay
processFooArray([a, b, c]); // error!
// ------------------> ~
```

Looks good.  The compiler is happy with `[a, b]`, but unhappy with `[a, b, c]`.

This approach probably also has its limits, especially if the library functions *produce* a value of "`Foo<A>` for some `A`"; maybe you can figure out what `A` should be based on the input to the library function, or maybe you just pick a random `A`, or `never`, or something.  I won't go farther down this road though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHZQLxTsATgSyQcygB8okBXAWwCMItioqEEAbCAQxRPOefvmQDaAXXoBvKALBYEkLKABcGbHnxDF-FAF8A3AChdoSFABiTADwBBKBAAewCEgAmcWIiQA+NFAAUSRRYBKNE9GFnYkPV0AeiioQ2gAZQQKCFMECywsNhAvDKyQMzNAYCIrW3snFw13NMt3d0j4qCSUtK8zACV3bwBjKkVLazsHZ1dkLoAzJkUai3cg1E92+cW9buRMOIRm1KY20qGK0Y9vSYRp81mAxW3Whahe4PuqE6YAyPGyJG7gHGQoNm63QgYGANyYeWy3kQLXBmWy12SOwQwiCol0UAxUCwEGAZCwKGhSIhIAAdBQ2GAoYjbp5CWkXghHqdvAAiAAWFAoLICPO0UBiDCYrA4ABoGGRgOjMQKALRy+UKxVK5Uq1UKzwAPy1WqlGIFAHJ2ZyWfqoDgXGw4HAcPgkGwqKxNnE2dA1khMFk8MAoAhxnFwNB9RZ9WLdfzYlQJVAg6a1mRmI4GNA8JgOD82PZEwB3HDANn-KCOHDjca0BzeuBkKiNX33dbYNhe6MafUk3SafQfL4-P4AoEgsHpOEgABMVJhQ-yCInKKgaMxWJxeIJ1Nh+TJFPHSMedKY3jDC+8AzKw0qbgmUxMFzmTL3Rq5-xcgR5Ybe7f0+kaABFzcoqDUABVPHQADBnKEYNCgAB+K8EDMICoEUJAIAAN1oSIBUcCBumYNgsh7FBdCwnC8OgLtvl+FApAQIErTSYljwOEZsTYRxkGYHINGELowzwrBFBYtikA4iQSTE8QBAAaTNFAAGsIBAWsLDUKAfw9HB-wuKShE8TQhCuUTxIkaS8CgeTFL9ZTFFCYUtCEDCYkcpznJcmJ9DdDY2HOOD1IIYCfCQZZSBJU8AHVczZVk2G5XQPO9PpYLMchqFofzfCClAzCgAAGEkAFZYvre4vG8GxFAACQAgBZAAZABRVgUiQYAgpsEk2UtCxgD-CUIFZOAsG6GL9Go2i4Ho4dvAENgxSofS+QFBBZOyXRRogOi10habZrFbp5vDaxMgQLAAEJoliNUVU1D9dCAA)