# How to define a (x: T) => void function type?

Tags: typescript

What I want is to define a type that can accept any `(x: T) => void` function:

```js
let a: MyType;
a = (x: number) => {};        // (x: number) => void
a = (x: string) => {};        // (x: string) => void
a = (x: SomeInterface) => {}; // (x: SomeInterface) => void
// ......
```

In this case, `type MyType = (x: any) => void` could work, but `type MyType = (x: unknown) => void` didn't work. How could I define the type without using `any`?

Comment: You can use `(x: never) => void;` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOAJEm), but what's the use case?  You could never *call* such a function without narrowing it first, and it's almost impossible to narrow functions because you can't easily test what their parameter types are.  I'm happy to write up an answer showing that `(x: never) => void` is the type you're looking for and why, but I'm concerned that this is an XY problem and you think this type is going to solve a problem that I doubt it will solve.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `unknown` is more appropriate here. Has the advantage of accepting any argument, while not allowing the function to assuming about the parameter.

Comment: @dwjohnston Yeah, you make a fair argument. I'll delete my comment, as you're right that it's probably a bad idea to recommend the use of `any`.

Comment: The reason why you get `never` here is because of *contravariance* of functions in their parameter types, as enforced by [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types). If you hand me a function but have forgotten whether that function accepts `A` or whether it accepts `B`, it is not safe for me to just decide to give it an `A` or a `B`.  The only thing safe would be something that's both an `A` *and* a `B`, or `A & B`.  If `A` and `B` are mutually exclusive, that's `never`.

Comment: GjfLeo if you respond to me, please mention @jcalz so I'm sure to be notified.

Comment: you can use generic

type UnknownFunction = <Type>(value: Type) => void; const a : UnknownFunction = (x) => {}; 

Then pass the type when you call the function like a<string>("myString"); or a<number>(5);

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009712/how-to-define-a-x-t-void-function-type#comment130676569_74009712) No, [you can't](https://tsplay.dev/w17y8m).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the comments. I'm defining a Vue component and want to use this type in the prop, because (at least I think) I can't use generic type as prop type. So I want to define the prop as `{item: unknown; func: (x: any) => void; }`, replacing `{item: T; func: (x: T) => void; }`.

Comment: That use case would not be addressed by the type you're asking for.  The type `{item: unknown; func: (x: any) => void}` is usable but not safe (since `func` might not really accept the same type as `item`), and the type `{item: unknown; func: (x: never) => void}` is safe but not usable.  You *need* generics here, and the best way to use them would presumably have to do with how you're using it.  I don't know anything about Vue, so I'd need to see a [mre] without that as a dependency to advise.

Comment: So, at this point, what do you want to do with this question?  You could leave it as-is, and the answer is "the type you're asking for is `(x: never) => void`, which is an essentially useless type".  Or you could edit with something more like your real use case, and we can see if there's a way to use generics.  Let me know (and mention @jcalz still)

Comment: @jcalz I think `(x: never) => void` could be the answer to this question. Maybe I should find some way to use generics as Vue component props later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a function type to which you can assign `(x: X) => void` no matter what `X` is, and you don't want to use [the unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), and you are presumably using [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), or at least [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types).

If so, then you need to use `(x: never) => void`, where the parameter is of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

```
let a: (x: never) => void;
a = (x: number) => { console.log(x.toFixed(2)) }; // okay
a = (x: string) => { console.log(x.toUpperCase()) }; // okay
a = (x: SomeInterface) => { console.log(x.a.toFixed(2)) }; // okay
```

That's because function types are [*contravariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in their parameter types, which means that `((x: X)=>void) extends ((y: Y)=>void)` if and only if `Y extends X`. Note that the position of `X` and `Y` have flipped; it's `Y extends X`, not `X extends Y`.  That means the type of a function *varies* in a way *counter* to the type of its parameters.

Aside: you can convince yourself this must be true if someone asks you for a function of type `(y: Y)=>void` because they want to pass it a value `y` of type `Y`.  If you hand them a function `f` of type `(x: X)=>void` where `Y extends X`, then everything's fine when they call `f(y)`, because every `Y` is also an `X`.  But if you hand them a function `g` of type `(z: Z)=>void` where `Z extends Y`, then the call `g(y)` could explode.  After all, every `Z` is also a `Y`, but that doesn't mean every `Y` is also a `Z`.  What if `Y` is `{a: string}` and `Z` is `{a: string; b: string}`?  Then the function `g` might be `z => console.log(z.b.toUpperCase())` and `g({a: ""})` will cause a runtime error. See [Stephan Boyer's blog post on co/contra-variance](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823104433/https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) for more information.

---

Anyway, if you want to find a single parameter type `Y` where `((x: X) => void) extends ((y: Y)=>void)` for *all possible* `X`, then by contravariance, `Y extends X` for all possible `X`.  The only type in TypeScript that works that way is `never`, the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).

And that gives you `(x: never) => void`.

Which is not great.

---

The type `(x: never) => void` is essentially unusable in TypeScript, mostly because function types cannot easily be [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).  Since `never` is an impossible type, you won't find yourself with a value of type `never` to call that function:

```
a(3); // error! 
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
a("hello"); // error! 
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
a(iFace); // error! 
// Argument of type 'SomeInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

For other wide types like [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) you could at least do type guard tests like [`typeof` tests](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards):

```
const u: unknown = ...;
if (typeof u === "string") {
    console.log(u.toUpperCase()); // okay
}
```

But for function types, there's not much to be done.  TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript, and at runtime, functions don't keep track of argument types.

The only way I can think of to deal with `(x: never)=>void` is to try calling it and catch runtime errors.  You could write a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like

```
function accepts<T>(f: (x: never) => void, v: T): f is (x: T) => void {
    try {
        f(v as never);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (accepts(a, "string")) {
    a("okay"); // "OKAY"
} else if (accepts(a, 456)) {
    a(123); // "123.00"
} else if (accepts(a, iFace)) {
    a(iFace); // "1.00"
}
```

But all that tells you is that the function doesn't throw a runtime error if you call it with the intended argument.  It can have bizarre side effects (what if the function changes state somewhere?  Now you've either changed the state twice, or done something invalid).  Even without side effects, the mere fact that no runtime error occurs isn't really the kind of strong typing guarantee you want.

So `(x: never) => void` is almost certainly not really the type you're looking for, even if it is the answer to your question as asked.

---

Since your actual use case involves a function/argument *pair*, then the type `(x: never) => void` is not what you want.

The type `(x: never) => void` falls out of the "infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" of `(x: X)=>void` for all `X`, also expressible as an [existential type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) which might be written as `<∃X>(x: X)=>void` if TS directly supported such types, which it doesn't.  The type `<∃X>(x: X)=>void` is useless ("I'm a function that accepts *some* type of argument but I won't tell you which one, tee hee").

But a pair would look like `<∃X>{f: (x: X)=>void; x: X}` and is suddenly quite usable ("I have a function `f` that accepts *some* type of argument.  I won't tell you what that type is, but I also have a value `x` of that type, so if you want to call `f` you can do so with `x`").

Without native support in TypeScript for existential types, you'd need to work around it somehow.  But that's out of scope of the question as asked. If you're interested you could look for other questions about existential types, such as [How to type an array of generic functions in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69304643/2887218).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeycAXMgIwA0yARpQEzIC+AUAuiAM5jLAAYogiUM2PJFgjkAXhJlKtBszbsANhH4VkACgAelEBABu0AJRyAfMhPpgAEwDc7OHL2HkIAK6Z6F6wUuXnRNADp1dABzAzCwdEFgfQgHXSZzS1YnZAB6HOR0AGs4AE9XdwNKPihQKMtZG1JgnlCICOjY+IBVAAce6ABhOB4IXQy2bLyC4rK3eUq0LFx8aSR6xuRm1vaY-TC4OISklLTxrNz8otL2G7nkAG12ZGePI19-KHWg7hbwyN3Dolkql0pkaE8XgtqrUvk0ftt-p10L1+lAhiMxmCIc8FuJllJCBBYZt4X8OnsDvEgSdQWoALr3ACycDAAAswjBIugoLpmWywlA4CAHFgxsgAFTIADM5jpLnYYCgJRI2LIuhlF2Q0Cg3IAhMgAIJQKK+CDgAowZBgEr9ZAAch8fmgdoEPC86G0PB4wCiIDg9E0VvQyB6cEF2CkFqtNpQDtMzrCqrgugARKyIOpIinLFNtXrDcbTeb0Jbrba7dCQFEXcA3SAPWQvT6-QGUPEQ2G4BHoFGy7HjGYoHbEy81UIROZJvk81B9UaTdhi6WY-a8ZICCIa3WG8Nvb7-YH26Hw1oeyXo+WBwn2KxNiyEKy9ESVTebs1+N5KN4QIV6wB3EB3HuKU6DTDMszocckAZPl2U5dBuV5Fl2UFYVRUsSUZTldhgEtXQ+3Pbw5FkeQU0rKJsxVUctjJGJvEOFFBmGUYMinaZrg4dgYG-BAwGAbgyAQJAejAHgAB4ABUrF0GBKAWK9PkCOxHDoExKAk8xKEtWtXmQDSlPsBwqJeRVlWIVVRxgXQTEbLx40+FxR1vBB70fXRn3M0dRygLRvCgQD4HUEZHJeDhvN8-yrSgbwIBcTjcL0RBhNE3Q4FA8js0sTyXmTFMrhKbM2JTAB5ABpA0AE0UxvLUgpQBLUqEiARJ4VK6AAFgAVgANnGbLnmTKgmBlIqhqlMIAAYJuq28MxGAQ8KS5qUrSgRhDWLKk10KCiVGybppvIA)